# Django type hint for model object (single)

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm looking for type hint on an model object instance class:

```
>>> Device.objects.get(pk=31)
<Device: Device object (31)>
>>> device = Device.objects.get(pk=31)
>>> type(device)
<class 'inventory.models.Device'>
```

I'll be passing above into a function which will be performing some action but i can't figure out what to use for the device object in the function where type hinting will take place?

```
def do_something(device: ???) -> bool:
    if device.id:
        some_logic
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference type as such

```
from inventory.models import Device

def do_something(device: Device) -> bool:
    # IDE will pick up attributes/methods linked to the model Device
    if device.id:
        some_logic
        return True
```

Comment: Nice, though about this too but couldn't tell if that was the best way? Are there any alternatives or this is the way?Thank you

Comment: @sngx that's the only way, i can point you to [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is Dependency inversion, you can pass data as **@Mike Jones** said

```
def do_something(device: Device) -> bool:
```

in general this pattern used with classes, I suggest for you to read more about it to know how you can implement it without any problems

problems I mean if you want to edit your code in future or change somethings on your classes